# How to export specific table from SQL Server database to CSV file with quotes around fields using command line?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, command-line, export-to-csv, bcp

I want to export an entire table from a SQL Server database.

The requirements are:

1. values should be quoted with double quotes.
2. Some values are really long, so the method should support very long values.
3. A 'NULL' value shuold be exported to the CSV as an empty string (i.e ,"",)
4. I don't know what the columns are, just the database table name, so please don't propose queries that explicitly contain the column names

Example row:

```
1,some
very

long
value
which might contain a comma,
or a newline, etc...,9,\path\tofile,444,X,,2011-01-01,
```

should be exported as:

```
"1","some
very

long
value
which might contain a comma,
or a newline, etc...","9","\path\tofile","444","X","","2011-01-01",
```

I have tried using `BCP`:

```
bcp TABLENAME out TABLENAME.csv -U username -P password -S server -c -t','
```

but it doesn't surround values with quotes.

Thanks

Comment: In order to replace NULL by empty string, you need to know the columns names and write something like ISNULL(col, ''). If you don' know the columns name, you will probably have to write some dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
bcp "select quotename(isnull(col1, \"\"), '\"') as col1 from db.schema.table" queryout TABLENAME.csv -U username -P password -S server -c -t','
```

Don't know what your definition of "long values" is, but `QUOTENAME()` has limit of 128 characters.  If you have to support longer than that, then try `CONCAT()`, or roll your own function.  For escaping double quote, you can also try using CHAR(34).